Principle of Mathematical Induction: A little variation of its proof.
I am writing my own math note currently and I decided to introduce mathematical induction in a new way. I make reference to $\mathit{Introduction\,To\,Real\,Analysis}$ by $\mathit{Robert\,G\,Bartle\,and\,Donald\,R\,Sherbert}$. For illustrate purpose I $\mathit{simply}$ restate here:
$\mathbf{Principle\,of\,Mathematical\,Induction}$
Given a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ which satisfied

1$\,\in A\,;$

$k+1\in A$ whenever $k\in A$.


Then $A=\mathbb{N}$.

Suppose $A\neq\mathbb{N}$ and we prove by contradiction. From the assumption made earlier we chose one element $x\in\mathbb{N}\setminus A$. By $\mathit{well\,ordered\,property}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ we let $l\in\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ and $l$ is the $\mathit{least\,element}$ of $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$. Next, observe that $l>1$ since $1\in A$. If $l>1$ then $l-1$ is still a natural number but $l-1\notin\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ becasue $l-1<l$ and $l$ is the smallest elements of $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$. So we have no choice to let $l-1\in A$. Now if we let $k=l-1$ then by definition $k\color{Red}{+1}=(l-1)\color{Red}{+1}=l\in A$. But this a contradiction since $l$ is the least element of $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$. So the assumption that $A\neq\mathbb{N}$ is false and $A=\mathbb{N}$ is true.

In my note, I didn't introduce the $\mathbf{Principle\,of\,Mathematical\,Induction}$ yet. Instead, I introduce an example:
$$
P=\{n\vert\,n^2\geq n\}
$$
After that, assert $P=\mathbb{N}$ and observe $1\in P$ and the property that $k+1\in A$ whenever $k\in A$ also satisfied by $P$ in my proof. This should also be able to introduce the $\mathbf{Principle\,of\,Mathematical\,Induction}$ but in a different way. But I found confusion in my proof and I $\mathit{roughly}$ present here:
$\mathbf{Proof\,in\,my\,note}$

Prove by contradiction so we assume $P\neq\mathbb{N}$. Likewise we can choose element $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus P$ so that $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\notin P$. Right, now we do not need the well ordered property of $\mathbb{N}$ to introduce a specific least element $s$ like we did in proof above. Because $n\in\mathbb{N}$, squaring $n$ will greater or equal to itself automatically. So we have $n\in P$. This is a contradiction since we took $n$ from $\mathbb{N}\setminus P$. Resulted that $P=\mathbb{N}$.

Is this proof still acceptable? Thanks for the answers and helps!

@lulu Yes! My bad, I forgot to mention that $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$

Your proof is correct, but it may be seen as a direct proof instead of a proof by contradiction. As you mentioned, the main fact is that $n^2$ is always greater than or equal to $n$ when $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

@CarlosLicea Oh yes that’s right. It can be prove directly. Thanks.

It might interest you to know that on this site, a Markdown parser will convert *italic* to italic and **bold** to bold without having to resort to the clumsy construction of formatting text inside of $\LaTeX$ math mode.

@SammyBlack  Got it, thanks.
